# Fetching third-party app's resource usage and statistics in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-application, taskmanager, android-profiler

I have learnt the basics of Android and want to develop an app (Similar to **Task manger for Android**). I want to know how to fetch the **resource** (CPU, Memory, Battery) **usage** and **statistics** of **third-party apps**(Gmail, Whatsapp,..) in **Android Studio**.

I went through the documentation and found about **Android Profilers**. **But, this can be used to find resource usage of app that we are currently developing and not for third-party apps**. Can someone help me out with relevant information?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio Profilers rely on shell commands on behalf of the app to get CPU or memory usage, so that's why it only shows resource usage for that app.

Comment: May I know if there is any way to get resource usage of 3rd-party apps?

Comment: For CPU usage you can looking into Linux procfs, for memory there's an Android command line tool called dumpsys.